# Why does AWX expect to see files in /etc/tower when inventory file specifies docker_compose_dir=/tmp/awxcompose?

Tags: ansible-tower

I have been using the official install guide for AWX found at [github](https://github.com/ansible/awx/blob/devel/INSTALL.md)

The web interface says only "Internal Server Error".

The docker log contains,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/awx-manage", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('awx==7.0.0.0', 'console_scripts', 'awx-manage')()
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/awx/__init__.py", line 126, in manage
    prepare_env()
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/awx/__init__.py", line 91, in prepare_env
    if not settings.DEBUG: # pragma: no cover
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 79, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 66, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 157, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/awx/settings/production.py", line 84, in <module>
    include(settings_file, optional(settings_files), scope=locals())
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/split_settings/tools.py", line 101, in include
    with open(included_file, 'rb') as to_compile:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/etc/tower/conf.d/credentials.py'
2019-09-20 16:52:33,174 INFO exited: callback-receiver (exit status 1; not expected)
2019-09-20 16:52:34,176 INFO gave up: callback-receiver entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
RESULT 2
OKREADY
No previous hash foundRESULT 2
```

My awx inventory file contains

```
localhost ansible_connection=local ansible_python_interpreter="/usr/bin/env python"

[all:vars]
ansible/awx_task
dockerhub_base=ansible
dockerhub_version=latest
awx_task_hostname=awx.nibbl.yo
awx_web_hostname=awxweb
postgres_data_dir=/tmp/pgdocker
host_port=80
host_port_ssl=443
#ssl_certificate=
docker_compose_dir=/tmp/awxcompose
```

[root@awx installer]# netstat -tlpn

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1317/master         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1028/sshd           
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      1317/master         
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      23364/docker-proxy- 
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1028/sshd
```

Comment: This smells like a bug to me. Have you reported it yet?

Comment: No. I suppose I should.